# CSS linking on pages

Tags: css

I have a stylesheet located in /main directory.  I have an index page in the /main directory which has include for header and footer.  I also have files in /main/page/xpage that use the headers and footers from the /main directory but the css won't display.

How do I make it so the css will be linked correctly in the files in the /main directory and the /main/page/xpage files?

In the header there is a link to the css.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="xxx.css" type="text/css" />
```

I can only assume that when the files in the /main/page/xpage directory includes the header that it can't find the css file because it is a ref to the page and the ref of the index file and files in the sub directories are in different locations.

Comment: There should be some more tags than just CSS.

Comment: Is `/main` in the root directory of your site?  How is your site set up - is it in a virtual directory or is it the main site?  If both answers are yes then b1-'s answer should be correct

Comment: Use an absolute URL rather than a relative one. ie start with a slash and define your entire URL path. That way your CSS path will be valid no matter what path the page is in.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/main/page/xpage/xxx.css">
```

First `/` mark that browser use path from site root like `example.com/`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/main/page/xpage/xxx.css">
```

Both examples give identical css